# Delegate pattern without storyboard or segue

Tags: swift, delegates, viewcontroller

I am learning to get a solid understanding of the delegate pattern. A lot of code examples in iOS uses two `ViewControllers`, which involve `prepare(for segue:...)`.

I want my program to use only one `ViewController` with a delegate protocol but no segue or storyboard. The `ViewController` has a button to execute a simple delegate method, let's say add a number.

The `ViewController` Class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, theDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

// It is here I got stuck
// How do I set delegate = self without out involving segue or the     storyboard at all? Do I need to instantizate the dedecated delegate class and how?
// To conform to delegate -- theDelegate
func add(num: Int) {
    // Output result on ViewController
}

func minus(num: Int) {
    // Output result on ViewController
}
}
```

The dedicated `Delegate` Class:

```
protocol theDelegate: class {
func add(num: Int)
func minus(num: Int)
}

class ClassDelegate: NSObject {
weak var delegate: theDelegate?

func x() {
    delegate?.add(num: 100)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @PhillipMills should be correct, just to add some notes about naming conventions from [this](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44688642/7113238) for you to get better code quality.

> - You should use uppercase for types (and protocols), lowercase for everything else
> - No need to inherit from NSObject unless you want something from the ObjC world, whether working with ObjC or use KVO

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. @PhillipMills I am not very sure what you mean, are you saying that I am not using the delegate pattern properly?

Answer (score 3):

If your view controller is the delegate, then your class naming is confusing.  What you call `ClassDelegate` isn't going to be any kind of delegate but, rather, a "Worker" that **uses** a delegate.  However....

```
var worker = ClassDelegate()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    worker.delegate = self
    worker.x()
}
```

Comment: Oh I see. I think I got it the other way around. So the class adopted the protocol is the real delegate class, and my so called ClassDelegate is just the protocol, probably should be renamed to ClassProtocol is that correct? Sorry, English is not my first languge.

Comment: `ClassDelegate` is only related to the protocol because it uses it.  Really, there's no reason for it to be called "delegate" or "protocol".  Consider a table view; it uses a delegate but we don't name it in any way related to the delegate protocol.

Comment: I see. Thank very much for helping me clear this up. :)